# When taking nlargest in pandas dataframe, is there a way to ignore column with NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas

When taking nlargest in pandas dataframe, is there a way to ignore column with NaN values? If say I want to pick 5 column headings with the 5 largest values, and if some of the columns has NaN values, then the column is ignored. If the number of columns with finite values is smaller than 5, then pick all the column headings with finite values (<5).

Comment: Can you post an example? I tried to repeat your task and got all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlargest` takes the n top rows sorted descendingly by the `columns` passed to the method.  If there are NaN values that get to the top then it will include these.  If you wan to ignore rows in which NaN values exist in the columns that were sorted by then do this:

```
# assume a variable 'columns' exist that defines what columns to sort
# by.  You'll have to assign this yourself.  Also assign 'n' yourself.
df = df.dropna(subset=columns)
df = df.nlargest(n, columns=columns)
```